# Read or emulate NFC card with Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, ndef, hce

Can I read or emulate with Android 4.2.2 (on a Galaxy S4) ISO/IEC 14443B (NFC) cards like SRI 512?

If yes what can I emulate? All the card data?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The SRI 512 is not an NFC card. Instead it's partially based on ISO 14443 Type B (lower layers only). Current Android NFC devices do not support *reading* (or even detecting) these types of cards. Android does not make use of the (proprietary) polling and selection protocol that would be required to support these cards.

Moreover, you can't emulate such a card with your device. This has multiple reasons:

1. Android supports host-based card emulation (HCE) only starting with Android 4.4. Consequently, the Galaxy S4 (running *stock* Android 4.2.2) would only support secure element based card emulation.
2. Android HCE is only capable of emulating ISO/IEC 14443-4 cards (and only if they make use of AID based application selection (file structures as defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4)) or sometimes(?) FeliCa cards.

Comment: SRI 512 is yes nfc card my friend.
do you have another idea how can i emulate this card?not with android?

Comment: The SRI512 (seems to be called T25TB512 now?) is certainly not NFC (and not even follows the full ISO 14443 Type B standard). It uses ST's proprietary anti-collision command (PCall16) an consequently is not detected by any current Android NFC devices (since these don't poll using that command).